# How to get a returned value of an insert function called by asp:ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, objectdatasource

I'm using an `asp:ObjectDatasource` to handle an insert (done through Linq to SQL) to my SQL database. The insert function returns an integer.

My problem is that how could I get the returned value of the function. Should I manually call the insert function through code behind or could I get it from the `asp:ObjectDataSource` as a key/value pair like how I send data through the `asp:ObjectDataSource` for the insert function to use?

Here's the insert function code:

```
public static int InsertSpotlightList(string spotlight_list_name)
        {
            ALI_DBDataContext ctx = new ALI_DBDataContext();

            DAL.Plugin_Spotlight_List temp_spotlight_list = new Plugin_Spotlight_List();
            temp_spotlight_list.Spotlight_List_Name = spotlight_list_name;
            temp_spotlight_list.Spotlight_List_IsDeleted = false;
            temp_spotlight_list.Spotlight_List_ForMall = false;

            try { 
                ctx.Plugin_Spotlight_Lists.InsertOnSubmit(temp_spotlight_list);
                ctx.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {  }

            return temp_spotlight_list.Spotlight_List_Id;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, you need to use: the OnInserted event of the `asp:ObjectDataSource`.

Here's an example:

```
protected void ObjDS_OnInserted(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    var ret_val = e.ReturnValue;
}
```

Sorry for the trouble. Should've researched more until I really can't think of a solution.